# IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code doesn't work with some object ( in Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm new to VSCode. I noticed that code completion (intellisence) doesn't work with some object. I searched on the web but I didn't find an answer.
My problem is that with some object intellisens works fine, like on the picture below
[image]
With other object I don't get any hint.

[image]

What is surprising in Intractive window everything is ok
[image]

```
from xml.dom import minidom


doc = minidom.parse("alarmBlocks.xml")
doc.  # there is no hint

import numpy as np

p = np.arange(1,14,0.1)
p.  # here I can see all the methods
```

Could you please give me some hints where I should look for solution of this problem?
Thank you in advance.

I reinstaled Python extension but without results.
Settings in launch.json are listed below

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {

    },
    "python.languageServer": "Default",
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "venv"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for a [mre]?

Comment: This is really a problem. I have submitted it to [github as a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3946)

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete and intellisense provided by `Pyalnce` rely on **Typeshed**.

I submit this problem to [Typeshed github](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/9724).

However, they said incomplete definitions are "normal". So we have to wait for their solution at present.

You can follow up on the issue to get real-time information.